# Android ListView setting height

Tags: android, android-listview, measure

We have an Android application with ListView, containing N items. For setting the height of ListView component, we use this method:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

The height is measured bad in the first run. If the method is called later (e.g. after reloading the ListView data becouse of change), the height is correct.

It seems that problem is in

```
int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
```

where the value desiredWidth is -2147483648 after first call, but -2147483368 after other calls and the height is set correctly.

Is there any way to change this behaviour and get the height correctly in the first call?

Comment: Setting the height of `ListView` component? Are you kidding!

Comment: you need use `getViewTreeObserver()` for getting correct width in first time, getWidth values is incorrect because View not created yet

Comment: shayan pourvatan: Thank you, using this solved the problem. If you make you comment an answer, I can accept it.